# C# Silverlight MediaElement wont play mp3 from web

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement

Hi Ive been pulling my hair out over this for the last couple of days, I have a mediaelement in a Silverlight App written in C#

Im trying to stream an MP3 over http and play it through the silverlight app. Although it keeps catching an exception that says

> AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR

The mp3 will not play and the MediaElement.MediaOpened event never fires

After searching on the net it appears this error is due to a curropt source but the mp3 plays fine when I point a webbrowser at the mp3.

heres the code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Uri source = new Uri("http://www.sm-testing.co.uk/mixes/youdontknow.mp3");
            mediaElement1.Source = source;
            mediaElement1.MediaFailed += new EventHandler<ExceptionRoutedEventArgs>(mediaElement1_MediaFailed);
            mediaElement1.MediaOpened +=new RoutedEventHandler(mediaElement1_MediaOpened);


        }


        void mediaElement1_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show( e.ErrorException.ToString());
        }

        private void mediaElement1_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            mediaElement1.Play();
        }
```

Comment: What is the size of the MP3? are you sure you are receiving the whole stream(MP3) in correct format?

Comment: @AllanChua Hi, yes the mp3 is fine, Ive just tried it with the windows sample wma and I get the same thing, The exception is instant and I cant see the app trying to make a connection to the site looking at netstat

Comment: What i want to ask is did you try to use a quick watch if the source of the player is fully received?

Comment: Are you loading it from the same domain as your Silverlight App? If not, do you have cross domain policy file in place in the root of www.sm-testing.co.uk?

Comment: +1 for providing a live link and code (makes it easy to check, but not such a great thing for your security). You might also want to turn off folder browsing on your website :)

Comment: Thanks for the tips although that site is my sandbox so , the onlything is I might get sued for letting people listen to the mp3 hope 50 cent doesn't go on stackoverflow, I'm already looking into the clientaccesspolicy and crossdomainpolicy after reading @HiTechMagic answer, I ll report back shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have used an actual URL in your example. I checked your site and there is no http://www.sm-testing.co.uk/ClientAccessPolicy.xml file or http://www.sm-testing.co.uk/crossdomain.xml file.

Without either of those files ([preferably ClientAccessPolicy.xml](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/introduction-to-data-and-networking/how-to-use-cross-domain-policy-files-with-silverlight) as the other is an old Flash compatibility format and missing some features) Silverlight will only retrieve files from the domain it is hosted on. This is a security feature to stop Silverlight app taking data or images from just *anywhere* without permission.

Example ClientAccessPolicy.xml below allows any access to any http or https request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
      <cross-domain-access>
        <policy>
          <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
            <domain uri="http://*" />
            <domain uri="https://*" />
          </allow-from>
          <grant-to>
            <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
          </grant-to>
        </policy>
      </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

*You don't need a crossdomain.xml as well unless you want to open up access to Flash apps too :)*

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, I added the 2 files as per what msdn says to do, however the thing still wont play, is casing important for the 2 files?. I've added them lowercase because msdn had them that way.

Comment: @Shutupsquare: You only need ClientAccessPolicy.xml but why do you  have it configured for SOAPAction only? Make it `allow-from http-request-headers="*"`. See updated example above.